# Wordpress Theme not applied to Blog Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, blogs

I'm activating a blog for my client's website (https://zukfinancialdp.com/).  It appears as though the Wordpress Theme (a customized default theme for 2020) styling is not being applied to the posts (https://zukfinancialdp.com/blog/).  There doesn't appear to be any custom css to be causing this, and I'm not seeing anything in the theme's php files that would indicate why (but I'm also not very php savvy).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 pages:

1. Home (set it as a Front page)
2. Blog (set it as Blog page)

Then move your whole content for your home page to the `front-page.php` file, use the `index.php` file for your blog posts, you need to redesign your `index.php` and `single.php`.